# JodaTime: Datetime with Z instead -04:00

Tags: java, jodatime

Hi I have a problem with joda time. I'm trying to get the 'Z' value at the end of datetime but couldn't :

I have tried with below syntax but no luck, not sure exactly

```
LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("GMT"));
```

Output:  2019-06-11T21:29:42.474

```
LocalDateTime currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forID("GMT"));
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");    
DateTime parsedDateTimeUsingFormatter
            = DateTime.parse(currentDateTime.toString(), fmt);
System.out.println(parsedDateTimeUsingFormatter);
```

Output: 2019-06-11T21:29:42.474-04:00

But I need like the below in GMT format:

Expected output: 2019-06-11T21:29:42.474Z

Comment: Why are you parsing the LDT back to a DateTime? Why not just `System.out.println(currentDateTime.toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC))`?

Comment: @AndyTurner: It would be better to avoid the LDT to start with - converting from local time can be ambiguous.

Comment: @JonSkeet sure... but in terms of going from a LDT to a DT, that's a pretty awkward way of doing it.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you just need to create a `DateTime` in UTC:

```
DateTime utcNow = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC);
System.out.println(utcNow);
```

It's not a matter of "just putting a Z at the end" - you need to make sure you're actually obtaining a UTC timestamp to start with.

Comment: Thankyou for response @jon Skeet I need the ouput in GMT timestamp with Z at the end like below
Expected output: 2019-06-11T21:29:42.474Z

Comment: @Nick: And what does the code in my answer do on your machine? (I don't have Joda Time handy right now, but I'd expect that either to do the right thing already, or just be a matter of using a different formatter - but the *value* should be correct.)

Comment: your code says DateTime utcNow = DateTime.now(DateTimeZone.UTC) But I need to see the output in GMT timestamp

Comment: @Nick: UTC *is* GMT (for most purposes). What's the output of the second line? You've said what you expect the output to be - what *is* the output?

Comment: I agree the output is 2019-06-11T22:09:58.027Z expected format. my only concern is I need the output GMT timezone

Comment: @Nick: 'Z' means UTC. Where you've kept on saying you want GMT, you really meant you want UTC - you just weren't aware of that. The time a short while ago *was* 2019-06-11T22:09:58.027Z.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
LocalDateTime localNow = LocalDateTime.now(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT").toZoneId());
```

Now That we have it set to GMT, we can proceed with;

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
String formatDateTime = localNow.format(formatter);
```

---

Answer will be in this format

> 2019-06-11T22:28:20.062Z

Comment: 1. cannot resolve method ofpattern();
2. cannot reolve method ZoneId() 
might be the joda versions are different

Comment: I found the solution with the below approach 

LocalDateTime localNow = LocalDateTime.now(DateTimeZone.forTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")));
        DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
        String formatDateTime1 = localNow.toString(fmt);
        System.out.println(formatDateTime1);

Comment: This is pure java. Not an added jar file. The imports where import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.TimeZone; Its good though you pulled it off